# How do I create a standalone jar from a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, jar, repository, package

I am trying to create a standalone jar file I don't think that `maven package` is properly packaging my dependencies into the package. Is there a way to force it to include them?

Comment: What makes you think that `maven package` is incorrect?

Comment: It didn't include all the dependencies that I needed

Comment: Future readers, this article helped me : https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternately you could use the [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) packaging of [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html).

By default maven builds and packages the compile output from the current project. The shade plugin allows to you create an 'uber' jar that contains not just your code but all of the dependencies into a single (sometimes quite big) jar.

Optionally allows you to [relocate classes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) in the packaging phase, meaning that your project can have completely private copies of it's dependencies without getting caught in jar hell.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an a basic example on how to use the maven assembly plugin [here](https://github.com/db80/java-skeleton).

You need only to clone the repository

```
git clone git://github.com/db80/java-skeleton.git
```

and run mvn package

```
cd java-skeleton && mvn package
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35359756/5678086 for creating full pack with all dependencies