# Create standalone jar out of multiple Maven projects

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have 3 maven projects say P1, P2 and P3. I have added dependency of P1 into P2 and P2 into P3. How to create standalone jar of P3?
I am using Eclipse and all three Maven projects are in same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You build project P3, and configure Maven to build a "fat jar" that contains all dependencies.

The most direct way is to build a `jar-with-dependencies` through the Maven assembly plugin:

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/927493 for details.

Comment: I am new to Maven. Can you please provide step by step guide?

Comment: Have a look at the linked answer which explains what you need to put into your pom.xml. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Then I need to go through required Maven docs as the answer is well suited for those who already know Maven. Thanks.

Comment: You know the pom.xml and the standard build commands (like `mvn install`), right? Then just copy and paste the _second_ xml snippet into the `<plugins>` section of your pom.xml. Now every `mvn install` will create an additional jar that contains all the dependencies.

Comment: I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217128/is-it-possible-to-build-a-java-project-only-once-using-eclipse-and-share/35359756#35359756 My P2 pom is <dependencies><dependency>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>p1</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies> and p3 pom is like - <dependencies><dependency>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>p2</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>.I cleaned all 3 using Maven clean and run Maven build on P3 using package assembly:single.

Comment: Result is Failed to execute goal on project p3: Could not resolve dependencies for project

Comment: I do not have main class in P3 project. What should I do?

Comment: What do you want to do with a standalone jar if you do not have a main class?

Comment: The jar will act as chunk of APIs which can be used in other projects

Comment: My advice: Don't do this. Maven has transitive dependency resolution, there is not need to bundle Apis into larger units.

Comment: Thanks for advice. What you suggest? Should I use multiple Eclipse projects and add dependent jars in build path?

Comment: If a project has a Maven dependency on P3, it _automatically_ also draws P2 and P1 because these are transitive dependencies. Just make sure that the pom.xml of all projects are correct.

Comment: P3 & P1 does not have any Maven dependency. P2 has Maven dependency. I included P1 into P2 and P2 into P3. I want to create P3 jar that automatically underneath includes P1 and P2.

Comment: You said in your question " I have added dependency of P1 into P2 and P2 into P3". This means that the pom.xml of P3 has a dependency on P2 and the pom.xml of P2 has a dependency on P1. What am I missing?

Comment: P1 pom - <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>p1</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging> 
</project>.

Comment: P2 pom - removed header section
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>p2</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging> 
<dependencies>  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>${selenium.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>p1</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>

Comment: P3 pom - 
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>p3</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>p2</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  
 </dependencies>

</project>

Comment: Exactly. So every project that declares a dependency on P3 will get P2 and P1 as well. No need to bundle them.

Comment: But I need to create standalone jar of P3 which will have references of P1 and P2 internally. This way I can use this jar for other projects.

Comment: And I still do not know why. Do these other projects _not_ use Maven?

Comment: Yeah, could be possible. Other projects may not use Maven.

Comment: Ok, so if you really have a project that neither uses Maven nor Gradle (which is rare these days), then this might be an option. But you are actually the first person I ever heard of that wants to build such an "api fat jar". Please think twice before you do it. I am out.

Comment: Thanks for your time JF. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) instead of the assembly plugin, as the latest assembly plugin (3.1.0) is very slow and spends over a minute packaging some of our jars. Switching to shade plugin resolved the issue. The plugin has a rich set of configuration options, for example to [create an executable jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html).

Here's a basic example without any custom configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I added this but still failed to execute. Could not resolve dependencies of other projects.

Comment: Did your project build before? And again: Please don't try to construct a huge api jar. Nobody does it, and if you are a Maven newbie you probably do not understand the consequences.