# Connect mongodb to minecraft plugin

Tags: mongodb, plugins, minecraft

I'm making a minecraft plugin for my minecraft server but I have an error that I can't found the solution. The context: I want to store the data of a player like level/xp/rank etc... Can you help me to do this part of the plugin, I'm a beginner in Java.

This is my code :

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import me.codexis.velocitylobbygeneral.commands.Lobby;
import me.codexis.velocitylobbygeneral.commands.MoveBot;
import me.codexis.velocitylobbygeneral.commands.Test;
import me.codexis.velocitylobbygeneral.event.*;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class VelocityLobbyGeneral extends JavaPlugin {

    private static VelocityLobbyGeneral instance;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        setInstance(this);

        // Listeners
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new OnJoinQuit(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new FormatChat(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Scoreboard(), this);

        // Channels
        getServer().getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord");

        // Commands
        new Lobby();
        new MoveBot();
        new Test();

        // Connection to database
        MongoClient mongoClient = (MongoClient) MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://myusername:@databasemc.ehssc.mongodb.net/VelocityMC?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
        MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("VelocityMC");
        MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("Vide");
        getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "Connected to Database");

        getLogger().info("=============================================");
        getLogger().info("   >>>> Velocity Lobby General Loaded <<<<   ");
        getLogger().info("=============================================");
   }

   @Override
   public void onDisable() {

       getLogger().info("===============================================");
       getLogger().info("   >>>> Velocity Lobby General disabled <<<<   ");
       getLogger().info("===============================================");

   }

   public static VelocityLobbyGeneral getInstance(){
       return instance;
   }

   private static void setInstance(VelocityLobbyGeneral instance){
      velocityLobbyGeneral.instance = instance;
   }
```

}

And this is my error :

```
[12:32:49 WARN]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at VelocityLobbyGeneral.jar//me.codexis.velocitylobbygeneral.VelocityLobbyGeneral.onEnable(VelocityLo 
bbyGeneral.java:38)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at 
org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:370)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at 
org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at 
org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:535)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at 
org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:449)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at 
org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:970)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:769)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at         org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:54)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at     org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:838)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at     org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:801)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:518)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at     net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:480)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1475)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(MinecraftServer.java:1274)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:319)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
[12:32:49 WARN]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:146)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:103)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
[12:32:49 WARN]:        ... 18 more
```

Please can anyone help me.

Pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>me.codexisphantom</groupId>
<artifactId>VelocityLobby</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>VelocityLobby</name>

<description>Official VelocityMC Plugin</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<url>www.velocity-net.com</url>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>papermc-repo</id>
        <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
        <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Mongodb dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Plugin added :

```
    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <phase>package</phase>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                     <descriptorRefs>
                         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                     </descriptorRefs>
                 </configuration>
             </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>
```

Comment: It seems you didn't export `com.mongodb.client.MongoClients` in your plugin

Comment: And how can I do that ? I use intellij

Comment: It depend if you are using Maven or gradle, how you import this, where the `com.mongodb.client` ... (in project or in dependency)

Comment: I use Maven and I import in dependency

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729094/10952503) can help you

Comment: I did what they said but it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean with didn't work?

Comment: I have error too and to be honest I'm a very beginner in java and I don't understand anything (sorry for respond so late)

Comment: No problem for late :) I have notification to know when youa re here. I understand. Here you have a dependency: MongoDB. You include it in your maven project, but you don't export it in your final jar. Can you [edit] your question to add your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Oupss, I think I forgot that I reformat all the code and delete all the parts linked with mongodb, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes. NP I will give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your maven configuration, you are importing MongoDB. So, it will compile and you will be able to use it when you will develop.

But, when you will compile, it will not be included in final jar. And such as MongoDB isn't in spigot, it will create your error (don't find MongoDB class).

To fix it, there is multiple tutorial [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729094/10952503), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/10952503), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35359756/10952503), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23986765/10952503) ... and I'm sure we can find more.

I suggest you to import mongo db like that :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.10</version> <!-- The version that you want -->
    <scope>compile</scope> <!-- In my maven project, it include this project in builded jar -->
</dependency>
```

You can find all versions of MongoDB [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver)

My full config which works :

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
 
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <phase>package</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>single</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <descriptorRefs>
                             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                         </descriptorRefs>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>

 <repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>sonatype</id>
       <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>

 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
       <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
       <version>3.12.10</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same problem.

Comment: I use your dependecy and the forty tutorial

Comment: Oh. Can you add your mongodb dep config in your question ?

Comment: I added it to the question (that's two weeks, no problem all person have a life)

Comment: Sure,  thanks no problem. I will take a look ! (Yes, I didn't see your edit)

Comment: @Codexis Update: I just create a new project with the given config and it works : I have mongoDB in the jar (which is around 2.2Mb). I just update project & make `maven install`

Comment: Can you give me the config pls

Comment: I just update my answer to show my full config